# How to split my laptop screen based on the number of cameras plugged on it with the AVI Class

Tags: .net, winforms, video, record

I'm a developing windows .NET recording application to surveillance my house when I am out of my home, I'm using the The AVICap class (located in the avicap32.dll file) What I want is If I have 4 USB cameras connected to my laptop I want the screen to be split based on the number of device connected to it, I'm searching on the web but I don't find a close approach to it, Can somebody help me to get the desired result, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I'll have a go. The AVICap exstern is usally bound to a picturebox control. I think, therefore, my first step would be to create a simple usercontrol (or inherited class) with a picture box and the DLL Import

```
[DllImport("avicap32.dll", EntryPoint = "capCreateCaptureWindow")]
static extern int capCreateCaptureWindow(string lpszWindowName,
    int dwStyle, int X, int Y,
    int nWidth, int nHeight, int hwndParent, int nID);
```

and bound them. Giving properties to allow a source to be selected. Then you can either automate creation of say MDI children forms for each attached camera from your main form, or allow the user to - each child obviously housing an instance of the control and passed the source from the automation/menu.

A simple to follow example of multithreaded web cam can be found here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20519/Webcamera-Multithreading-and-VFW